# Error when I'm trying to connect to Athena from power BI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi, aws-glue, amazon-athena

This error Show me:

> ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Simba][Athena] (1041) An error has been thrown from the AWS Glue client. Athena Error No: 15, HTTP Response Code: 400, Exception Name: AccessDeniedException, Error Message: User: arn:aws:iam::006244860144:user/amls-athenabi-user-dev is not authorized to perform: glue:GetDatabases on resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:catalog because no identity-based policy allows the glue:GetDatabases action.

My Policy for the IAM User to connect from Power BI

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:BatchCreatePartition",
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "glue:GetPartitions",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "glue:UpdateTable",
                "athena:GetQueryResults",
                "glue:DeleteTable",
                "s3:GetStorageLensConfigurationTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetIntelligentTieringConfiguration",
                "athena:StopQueryExecution",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "glue:UpdateDatabase",
                "athena:GetQueryResultsStream",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "glue:CreateTable",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetJobTagging",
                "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:DescribeMultiRegionAccessPointOperation",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "glue:GetPartition",
                "s3:DescribeJob",
                "glue:BatchDeleteTable",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "glue:DeletePartition",
                "s3:GetAccessPointForObjectLambda",
                "athena:BatchGetQueryExecution",
                "s3:GetStorageLensDashboard",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "glue:DeleteDatabase",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyForObjectLambda",
                "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAttributes",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "athena:ListQueryExecutions",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "glue:CreatePartition",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls",
                "glue:UpdatePartition",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicyStatus",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicy",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyStatusForObjectLambda",
                "glue:BatchGetPartition",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetAccessPointConfigurationForObjectLambda",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetDatabase",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointRoutes",
                "s3:GetStorageLensConfiguration",
                "glue:CreateDatabase",
                "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicy",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:athena:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:workgroup/primary",
                "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:catalog",
                "arn:aws:s3:::datos-parquet-desarrollo"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:BatchCreatePartition",
                "glue:UpdateDatabase",
                "glue:CreateTable",
                "glue:DeleteDatabase",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:GetPartitions",
                "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
                "glue:UpdateTable",
                "glue:BatchGetPartition",
                "glue:DeleteTable",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetDatabase",
                "glue:GetPartition",
                "glue:CreateDatabase",
                "glue:BatchDeleteTable",
                "glue:CreatePartition",
                "glue:DeletePartition",
                "glue:UpdatePartition"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:catalog"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding permission `glue:GetDatabases` to the user as stated by the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `glue:GetDatabases` action on the resource `arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:catalog` in the policy. You need to update your IAM policy that is applied to the role you are using